# Select unique field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
TableA
----------------
ID (pk)   Name
1         A
2         B
3         C
4         A
5         D
6         A
7         B
8         A
9         D
10        C
....
```

I need to randomly extract with a `SELECT TOP 5 ID, Name FROM TableA`
with Name that must be unique within the 5 records.

I'm trying :

```
;WITH group
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY NewId()) rn
    FROM    TableA
)
SELECT ID, Name
FROM group
WHERE rn = 1
```

but every time I have quite the same results.

I need to select between all the values for ID at random, assuring that Name will always be different for each record.

## I hope the problem is understandable. Any ideas?

Found a solution. It seems to work!

```
;WITH group 
AS ( 
SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY NewId()) rn FROM TableA ) 
SELECT top 5 ID, Name, NewId() [NewId] 
FROM group 
WHERE rn = 1 
ORDER BY [newid]
```

Comment: Your query works on SQL Server 2012 just renaming`group` as `[group]`. Different results each run

Comment: With SQL Server 2014 it doesn't work.

Comment: Please avoid posting your solution as a part of the question. Instead, answer your own question and accept your own answer. That way, people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is that although `newid()` is random, it may tend to be sequential.  Does this fix the problem?

```
WITH g as (
      SELECT ID, Name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(NewId()))) as rn
      FROM TableA
     )
SELECT ID, Name
FROM g
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #test(ID INT ,Name VARCHAR(1)) INSERT INTO #test(ID ,Name )
SELECT 1,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'B' UNION ALL SELECT 3,'C' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 5,'D'UNION ALL SELECT 6,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'B' UNION ALL SELECT 8,'A'UNION ALL SELECT 9,'D' UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'C'

SELECT T1.ID ,T1.Name FROM  #test T1
JOIN ( SELECT TOP 5 Name FROM #test T2 ORDER BY NEWID()
) A ON T1.Name = A.Name ORDER BY A.Name
```

Comment: I need to guarantee that the Names are unique between all the records every time I run the select.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH group
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY NewId()) rn
    FROM    TableA
)
SELECT top 5 ID, Name, NewId() [NewId]
FROM group
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY [newid]
```

Comment: Do es it work for you now? it is the same you post but `ORDER BY` added, it makes no sense to me. It is the same resultset ordered differently.